# JSF Bean Created Many Times When Trying To Login

Tags: spring, jsf, view, primefaces, request

I am trying to login to a web site that I am currently developing but I am not able to due to the fact that the login bean is been called/created many times having as a result the username and password to be null. I am using Spring with a custom login page and I tried to declare the bean as request and view scoped but nothing changed. Also the problem appeared when I tried to change the login page using primefaces components but even when I returned the page in its original state I was still having this problem. I running it on Tomcat 7.

The login.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div align="right" style="">
            <h:form id="loginFormId" prependId="false">
                <div id="loginFieldsPnlId">
                    <div id="loginFieldUsrContId">
                        <h:outputText id="outTxtUserNameId" value="Username:" ></h:outputText>
                        <h:inputText id="userName" required="true" value="#{loginMgmtBean.userName}" requiredMessage="Please enter username"></h:inputText>
                        <h:outputLabel id="outLblUserNameId" for="userName"></h:outputLabel>
                    </div>
                    <div id="loginFieldPassContId">
                        <h:outputText id="outTxtPasswordId" value="Password:"></h:outputText>
                        <h:inputSecret id="password"  required="true" value="#{loginMgmtBean.password}" requiredMessage="Please enter password"></h:inputSecret>
                        <h:outputLabel id="outLblPasswordId" for="password" ></h:outputLabel>
                    </div>
                    <div id="loginFieldPassContId">
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="rememberMe" value="#{loginMgmtBean.rememberMe}" label="Remember Me">Remember Me</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="loginBtnPanelId">
                    <h:commandButton id="btnLoginId" value="Login" action="#{loginMgmtBean.login}" styleClass="loginPanelBtn"></h:commandButton>
                    <h:commandButton id="btnCancelId" value="Cancel" action="#{loginMgmtBean.cancel}" styleClass="loginPanelBtn" immediate="true" ></h:commandButton>
                </div>
            </h:form>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h:messages></h:messages>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The LoginBean

```
package extra.beans;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.RememberMeServices;

/**
 * The Class LoginBean.
 */
@ManagedBean(name = "loginMgmtBean")
@ViewScoped
public class LoginBean {
    LoginBean(){
        System.out.println("constructor");
    }

    /** The user name. */
    private String userName = null;

    /** The password. */
    private String password = null;

    /** The remember me. */
    private String rememberMe = null;

    /** The authentication manager. */
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{authenticationManager}")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = null;

    /** The remember me services. */
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{rememberMeServices}")
    private RememberMeServices rememberMeServices = null;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{userDetailsService}")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService = null;
    /**
     * Login.
     *
     * @return the string
     */
    public String login() {
        try {
                    System.out.println("login: "+ userName);
                    System.out.println("login: "+ password);    
            Authentication result = null;
            if ("TRUE".equalsIgnoreCase(this.getRememberMe())) {
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(getUserName());
                RememberMeAuthenticationToken rememberMeAuthenticationToken = new RememberMeAuthenticationToken(
                        "jsfspring-sec", userDetails,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities());
                HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
                HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
                rememberMeServices.loginSuccess(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, rememberMeAuthenticationToken);
                result = rememberMeAuthenticationToken;
            } else {
                Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        this.getUserName(), this.getPassword());
                result = authenticationManager.authenticate(request);
            }
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
                        return "Secured";
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "NOOOOOOOOOOO";
    }

    /**
     * Cancel.
     *
     * @return the string
     */
    public String cancel() {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Logout.
     *
     * @return the string
     */
    public String logout() {
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        /**
         * Delete Cookies
         */
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE", null);
        cookie.setMaxAge(0);
        cookie.setPath(httpServletRequest.getContextPath().length() > 0 ? httpServletRequest.getContextPath() : "/");
        httpServletResponse.addCookie(cookie);
        return "loggedout";
    }

    /**
     * Gets the user name.
     *
     * @return the user name
     */
    public String getUserName() {
            System.out.println("get: "+ userName);
        return userName;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the user name.
     *
     * @param userName
     *            the new user name
     */
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
            System.out.println("set: "+ userName);
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the password.
     *
     * @return the password
     */
    public String getPassword() {
    System.out.println("get: "+ password);  
            return password;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the password.
     *
     * @param password
     *            the new password
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
    System.out.println("get: "+ password);  
            this.password = password;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the remember me.
     *
     * @return the remember me
     */
    public String getRememberMe() {
        return rememberMe;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the remember me.
     *
     * @param rememberMe
     *            the new remember me
     */
    public void setRememberMe(String rememberMe) {
        this.rememberMe = rememberMe;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the authentication manager.
     *
     * @return the authentication manager
     */
    public AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager() {
        return authenticationManager;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the authentication manager.
     *
     * @param authenticationManager
     *            the new authentication manager
     */
    public void setAuthenticationManager(
            AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the remember me services.
     *
     * @return the remember me services
     */
    public RememberMeServices getRememberMeServices() {
        return rememberMeServices;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the remember me services.
     *
     * @param rememberMeServices
     *            the new remember me services
     */
    public void setRememberMeServices(RememberMeServices rememberMeServices) {
        this.rememberMeServices = rememberMeServices;
    }

    public UserDetailsService getUserDetailsService() {
        return userDetailsService;
    }

    public void setUserDetailsService(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }
}
```

The applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <beans:bean id="navigator" name="navigator" class="extra.beans.Navigator" scope="session">
        <beans:property name="businessModel" ref="businessModel"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="loginMgmtBean" name="loginMgmtBean" class="extra.beans.LoginBean" scope="prototype">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="securityBean" class="extra.beans.SecurityHolderBean" scope="session">
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="businessModel" class="extra.business.model.BusinessModel" scope="prototype"></beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/extra" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="extra.dao.CustomJDBCDaoImpl">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <beans:property name="enableAuthorities" value="false"/>
        <beans:property name="enableGroups" value="true"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="usersByUsernameQuery">
            <beans:value>
                SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD, ENABLED
                FROM USER
                WHERE USERNAME = ?
            </beans:value>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery">
            <beans:value>
                SELECT USERNAME, ROLE_NAME
                FROM ROLE
                WHERE USERNAME = ?
            </beans:value>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="groupAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery">
            <beans:value>
                SELECT GROUP.ID, GROUP.NAME, AUTHORITY.AUTHORITY
                FROM `GROUP`, AUTHORITY, GROUP_MEMBER, `USER`
                WHERE `USER`.USERNAME = ? AND
                    GROUP_MEMBER.USER_ID = USER.ID AND
                    GROUP_MEMBER.GROUP_ID = GROUP.ID AND
                    AUTHORITY.GROUP_ID = GROUP.ID
            </beans:value>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
        <beans:property name="key" value="jsfspring-sec" />
        <beans:property  name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
        <beans:property  name="alwaysRemember" value="true" />
        <beans:property  name="tokenValiditySeconds" value="60" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="key" value="jsfspring-sec"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="rememberMeFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices"/>
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder">
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="databasePasswordEncrypter" class="extra.dao.DBPasswordEncrypterBean" init-method="encryptDBPassword" depends-on="dataSource">
        <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="selectQuery">
            <beans:value>
                SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD, ENCRYPTED
                FROM USER
                WHERE (ENCRYPTED = '' ||
                    ENCRYPTED IS NULL ||
                    ENCRYPTED = 'NO')
            </beans:value>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="updateQuery">
            <beans:value>
                UPDATE USER
                SET PASSWORD = ?, ENCRYPTED='YES'
                WHERE USERNAME = ?
            </beans:value>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

The securityContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/pages/secure/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/pages/unsecure/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/pages/public/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <sec:form-login login-page="/pages/public/login.jsf"/>
        <sec:remember-me key="jsfspring-sec" services-ref="rememberMeServices"/>
        <sec:logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID, REMEBER_ME_COOKIE" logout-success-url="/pages/public/login.jsf"/>
    </sec:http>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider ref="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider"></sec:authentication-provider>
        <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <sec:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
            </sec:password-encoder>
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
</beans:beans>
```

The web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation=
        "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"

    version="3.0">
    <!-- CONFIGURATION FILES both Bean definition and security -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/securityContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- CONFIGURATION FILES END HERE -->
    <!-- PROJECT STAGE START FOR DEVELOPEMENT MARK IT AS DEVELOPMENT, FOR TESTING, UAT, PRODUCTION REMOVE THIS -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- PROJECT STAGE END -->
    <!-- Enable JSF Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- Enable JSF Server End-->
    <!-- Integrate JSF and Spring -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Integrate JSF and Spring End-->
    <!-- Enable Spring Filter, Spring Security works on the concept of Filters -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- Enable Spring Filter End -->
    <!-- Welcome File  -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/pages/common/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <!-- Welcome File End-->
</web-app>
```

The faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <!-- Enable Spring -->
    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>
    <navigation-rule>
        <display-name>pages/secure/secured.xhtml</display-name>
        <from-view-id>/pages/secure/secured.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{loginMgmtBean.logout}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>loggedout</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/public/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect></redirect>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <navigation-rule>
        <display-name>pages/public/login.xhtml</display-name>
        <from-view-id>/pages/public/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{loginMgmtBean.login}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>Secured</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/secure/secured.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <navigation-rule>
        <display-name>pages/secure/secured.xhtml</display-name>
        <from-view-id>/pages/secure/secured.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{navigator.showAdminPersonalPage}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>adminPersonalDetails</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/secure/adminPersonalDetails.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

Comment: Don't define your bean in the spring context file. It should be managed by JSF and not Spring.

Comment: Why not? It was working before, being managed by spring.

Comment: If you do that your `@ViewScope` is useless. You have put `@ManagedBean` on there so you want it to be a JSF managed bean, then let it be such a thing.

Comment: @M.Deinum- What are you talking about? OP is injecting Spring business objects into his `@ViewScoped`. How does that affect the functioning of the JSF managed bean?

Comment: @SpyrosNonServiam - Where is the navigation rule for "NOOOOOOOOOOO"? If your logic results in an outcome of NOOOO, and no rule is specified for it, the `NavigationHandler` will most likely destroy the bean and recreate it to keep you on the same page

Comment: @kolossus I don't have but it doesn't matter. The problem exists putting the correct credentials (and the wrong ones but it just doesn't matter).

Comment: What is the reason for using view scoped bean for authentication, while the authentication result is in cookie, which would make authentication session scoped anyway? I also don't see your code for reading the cookie. Setters and getters in the same time are redundant and you should remove them. Just post the relevant code, not the whole class.